# How do I return a map from a function in XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

Let's say I have a function `f:get-map()` that returns a map.

How do I use the result of that function in another function?

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
<xsl:function name="f:get-another-map" as="map(*)">
  <xsl:variable name="result" select="f:get-map()"/>
  <xsl:map>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'key1'" select="map:get($result, 'key1')"/>
      <xsl:map-entry key="'key2'" select="map:get($result ,'key2')"/>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:function>
```

But that is rather cumbersome.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is, in the title you ask "How do I return a map from a function...?" and then in the first sentence you say you already "have a function f:get-map() that returns a map". So how does that function look? Do you want to simply return the result of the function call `f:get-map()`? Then use `<xsl:sequence select="f:get-map()"/>`. But I don't see what you need that function `f:get-another-map` for then at all, it would appear to me as cumbersome to have that second function at all if you only want to get the first function.

Comment: @MartinHonnen My example is probably a bit too simplified - but indeed, `xsl:sequence` does the trick, thanks.

Comment: I have morphed the suggestion from the comment into an answer so that you can accept it and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general to return any function call result from a function you use `xsl:sequence` with the `select` expression calling the function e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="f:get-map()"/>` returns the result of calling `f:get-map()`.